Can we start work after application of Blue Card in Germany?

I came on Job Seeker Visa with a validity of 6 months.
I got an offer 2 months before my Job Seeker Visa expiry date.
I had already contacted Aulanderbehoerde for Blue Card application and as per their requirement I submitted all the necessary documents within 2 days of getting offer.
However my company want me to start work within 2 weeks of time and also gave me 2 weeks time for joining.

In case if I didn't get any response from Auslanderbehoerde within this 2 weeks then how I can convince my employer? As my employer will ask confirmation from Immigration office.
Please guide on this urgently otherwise I may lose the opportunity.

I'm not familiar with German law, but in virtually all cases you have to wait for a visa or permit to be granted before you actually start living and working in a place. Does you job seeker visa give you permission to work?

@DJClayworth That's basically the question ;)

Yes,My Job seeker visa gives me a permission to work but only for 10 hours a week, however I have got full time employment.Can I start working based on approved hours?

@Asif As far as I know, it's 20 hours total per employer, basically a trial period of 10 hours a week for 2 weeks. You can definitely do that but you will soon find yourself in the same situation again. Your employer has to wait for your Blue Card before you can start working in earnest.

Thank you for clarification

You are not allowed to start working before your Blue card has been approved. It is not reasonable for your employer to expect this to be completed in two weeks. The legal delay is 90 days. If they have sponsored a Blue Card holder before, they must know this so you shouldn't need to convince them of anything.
I am sure your employer would be happy to see you start as soon as possible and it's common to include boilerplate making the contract contingent on obtaining the necessary permit but it would be concerning if would actually lose the opportunity after two weeks. Blue Card employment is for qualified work, restarting the recruitment process costs time and money and most German employees have notice periods between one and three months, sometimes even more, so it's not like they can fill your position within one week. Waiting 2-3 months for you is probably their best option.
Unfortunately, there is not much you can do about it and this is still going to be stressful. The only thing that's within your power is being proactive in your communication: stress you're still interested in the job, offer your future manager an informal chat, ask for stuff you could read to get up to speed, tell them you have submitted everything as soon as possible, ask their HR department if they have heard anything on their side or if there is anything else you could do to speed up the process, etc.
